# DialogService with no dependency on MainWindow

Tags: wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqKaV4d4PXg) but it is either my misunderstanding or a problem with the design but it seems to result in a circular dependency. As show the `DialogService` depends on the `MainWindow` and the `MainWindow` has a binding to the `MainWindowViewModel` that uses the `DialogService`. So the DialogService needs to be constructed after the `MainWindow` and the `MainWindow` needs the `DataContext` set after it is constructed. So the question is how do I build a `DialogService` with no dependency on `Window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dialog service is supposed to bring up a dialog which can for example be implemented using a `Window` or a `MessageBox`:

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    bool? ShowDialog();
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public bool? ShowDialog() => new DialogWindow().ShowDialog();
}
```

**DialogWindow.xaml:**

```
<Button IsDefault="True" Click="acceptButton_Click">OK (IsDefault=True)</Button>
<Button IsCancel="True">Cancel (IsCancel=True)</Button>
```

**DialogWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
void acceptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Accept the dialog and return the dialog result
    this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

[Window.DialogResult Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.dialogresult?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

Comment: Thank you. In keeping with MVVM I am assuming that `Click` would turn to `Command` and then have an associated `DialogWindowViewModel`

Comment: You inject the view model with the `IDialogService`. The view binds to a command of the view model.

Comment: I am assuming also that using MVVM I can bind the dialog result to the view model?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to bind to DialogResult?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: How else do I tell if the dialog returned Ok or Cancel?

Comment: You check the return value of the method in the view model.